# What is the correct Cloud Resource Manager URI for getIamPolicy on a Google BigQuery Dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

I would like to set a fine-grained, resource-specific IAM policy for a single Google BigQuery Dataset. The documentation I've found so far only explains how to get and set IAM policies for the project resource e.g. `https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project-id>:getIamPolicy`.

I am trying to get the policy for a resource within a project, specifically a Google BigQuery dataset with an API URL like this: `https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<project-id>/datasets/<dataset-id>`.

I have tried a number of obvious-looking URIs like

- `https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<project-id>/datasets/<dataset-id>:getIamPolicy`
- `https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project-id>/datasets/<dataset-id>:getIamPolicy`

but have hit 404 errors. Does anyone know the correct URL pattern for IAM policies for Google BigQuery Datasets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to get the policy for a resource within a project, specifically a Google BigQuery dataset ...

You already have it in your question - you should use  `GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectId>/datasets/<datasetId>` and in response you should look for `access` property

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets#resource):

> > Access is an array of objects that define dataset access for one or more entities. You can set this property when inserting or updating a dataset in order to control who is allowed to access the data. If unspecified at dataset creation time, BigQuery adds default dataset access for the following entities:
> >
> > access.specialGroup: projectReaders;  access.role: READER; 
> >     access.specialGroup: projectWriters; access.role: WRITER; 
> >     access.specialGroup: projectOwners; access.role: OWNER; 
> >     access.userByEmail: [dataset creator email]; access.role: OWNER;

And, if you want to change access - you should use `PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectId>/datasets/<datasetId>` or `PUT https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectId>/datasets/<datasetId>`